# why am I not being redirected in the browser after Mailchimp API oauth2 initial request is sent?

Tags: python, django, redirect, oauth-2.0, mailchimp

I am trying to set up Oauth2 with the Mailchimp API. So far things seem to be working correctly except that after having the user login at Mailchimp, the browser doesn't redirect back to my redirect_uri. It just stays on the Mailchimp login page.

For the code:

I redirect the user to the authorize url/mailchimp login:

`authorize_uri = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize?           response_type=code&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&redirect_uri=%s' % (settings.MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_ID, settings.MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri)`

my redirect_uri is `redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/mailchimp/connect'`

So the authorize_url redirects to the login page, and I login with credentials that absolutely work to login the regular non-oauth way. Also I see the 302 redirect with the code I need in my logs, but the browser seems to just refresh the Mailchimp login page and the view(I'm using django) for processing the GET request below is never triggered.

`[06/Jul/2016 02:31:43] "GET /mailchimp/connect?code=36ad22daa3d0f8b3804f7e340e5d50f1 HTTP/1.1" 302 0`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Your email_host, user, password and port match with your mail-chimp credentials? second thing you need to check mail-chimp api log for status. you will get some glimpse from there.